# Swift: Custom section header includes buttons to either delete rows or add a row for ONLY that section's rows

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview

I'm new to Swift, so please elaborate on your answer.

Basically I've created a custom header using a nib and created a subclass of `UITableViewHeaderFooterView` associating to the nib I created. The custom header contains two buttons which one is "Add Object" and when the user clicks on it, it should just insert a custom cell (Yes. My cells are custom cells that dynamically display when the application launches) row with some default data and the other is "Delete Object" which enables the edit mode and allows the user to delete rows. It also contains a label to display the title of that section header.

I don't want to use navigation control or create my buttons programmatically, so I'm just mentioning it before anyone gives me an answer like that. I will explain exactly what I've done and what I'm trying to do.

The problem I am having is whenever I click "Delete Object" it does enable the edit mode and displays the red circles, but to ALL sections. I only want it to show for the section I clicked it on. I've already tried to use canEditRowAt and it doesn't seem to work. The problem I keep getting is it either displays the red circles to just one section regardless which section I click the "Delete Object".

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, commit editingStyle: 
UITableViewCellEditingStyle, forRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {

    //There are two sections 

    switch indexPath.section {

    case 0:

        if editingStyle == .delete{
            //Updating data model before removing
            firstArray.remove(at: indexPath.row)

            tableView.deleteRows(at: [indexPath], with: .left)
        }

        else if editingStyle == .insert{

            firstArray.append(objects(name: "Test", second: "Cell", image: UIImage(named: "Unknown")!))
            let indexPath = IndexPath(row: firstArray.count - 1, section: 0)
            tableView.insertRows(at: [indexPath], with: .left)


        }
    case 1:

        if editingStyle == .delete{
            //Updating data model before removing

            secondArray.remove(at: indexPath.row)

            tableView.deleteRows(at: [indexPath], with: .left)
        }

        else if editingStyle == .insert{

            let indexPath = IndexPath(row: secondArray.count - 1, section: 0)
            tableView.insertRows(at: [indexPath], with: .left)
        }
    default:
        break
    }
}
```

For the buttons inside the nib, I did something similarly to how you would unwind from a viewController. I created the @IBAction outlets in the firstViewController (which is the datasource and delegate of the TableView) and inside the nib I control + clicked on each button and dragged the line to the firstResponder box and assigned it to the events I created. I've tested them and they work.

```
@IBAction func deleteTheObject(sender: UIButton){

    //This does show the edit mode and changes the buttons name each time 
    //it's clicked, but I only want it to enable the edit mode on the
    // section that the section's header "Delete Object" button was clicked on. 
    //NOT both sections

    if self.table.isEditing == true{
        table.setEditing(!table.isEditing, animated: true)
        sender.setTitle("Done", for: .normal)
    }
    else{
        self.table.isEditing = true
        sender.setTitle("Delete Object", for: .normal)
    }
}

@IBAction func addTheObject(sender: UIButton){
  //Should add row to section
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Add this to only allow, for example section1, editable

```
    override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, canEditRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> Bool {
        if indexPath.section == 1 {
            return true
        }
        return false
    }
```